# Oracle (ORA-02270) : no matching unique or primary key for this column-list error: when referencing a materialized view

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, oracle11g

I am getting the ORA-2270 error when I try to create some Oracle tables.

The error is quite simple from what I have read so far:

> It happens when the columns I reference in the foreign key do not
>   match a primary key or unique constraint on the parent table.

The problem is that my tables have several foreign keys, and I am trying to reference a PK column on a **materialized view** (because I do not have the chance of getting access to the real table, only the MV).

How can I then create my tables and reference them to the correct PKs in the materialized view given that MVs does not have PKs?

And generally talking... What is the common procedure once this problem occurs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "MVs does not have PKs". MVs can have PKs in Oracle. If you have access to making PK on your view - do it. If you don't have access - there is not much you can do about this. You can't create FK reference without enforcing PK constraint. You should replace all foreign key checks with EXISTS checks in your sql code when you update or insert.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction, @dmitriy-yankin. I thought that MVs could not have PKs in Oracle intended as "snapshots" of any table. I think I will have to ask for access because from your answer, I understand that this is not a common situation. Thanks again.